# How to get my other methods to correctly read from the array

Tags: java, netbeans-8

when I attempt to run this program it will accept the inputs but will only print out 0.0 0.0 0.0 for all prints. I need it to print the imputed numbers and then print the average to 2 decimal accuracy. Why is it only printing 0s and not the numbers put in

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class pcCalculate 


{
     double[] pcPrice = new double [10];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Quiz input = new Quiz();
        Quiz display = new Quiz();
        Quiz avgCalc = new Quiz();
        input.arrayInput();
        display.displayPCPrices();
        avgCalc.avgPCCalc();
}

public void displayPCPrices()
{
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pcPrice));
}

   public double avgPCCalc() 
   {
    int sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < pcPrice.length; i++)
        {
                 sum = (int) (sum + pcPrice[i]);
        }
double average = sum / (double)pcPrice.length;
return average;
   }
          public void arrayInput()
     {

    Scanner price = new Scanner(System.in);
     System.out.println("Enter Prices");
        pcPrice[0] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[1] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[2] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[3] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[4] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[5] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[6] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[7] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[8] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[9] = price.nextDouble();
  }
```

}

Comment: Make `pcPrice` a member variable in `pcCalculate` instead of a local variable in `main`.

Comment: when I do that all the inputs listed in main say non static variables cannot be referenced in main. I have been working on it and will edit my post in a sec to show my current progress

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow :) you've gotten a couple downvotes, probably because your question title is very vague. If you changed it to something clear and specific (e.g. "How to make main method functionality callable from other methods") you would probably get more and better answers :)

Answer (score 0):

Call your displayPCPrices method from your main and pass in pcPrice as a parameter:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class pcCalculate
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        double[] pcPrice = new double [10];

        Scanner price = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Prices");
        pcPrice[0] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[1] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[2] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[3] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[4] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[5] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[6] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[7] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[8] = price.nextDouble();
        pcPrice[9] = price.nextDouble();

        displayPCPrices(pcPrice);

    }

    public void displayPCPrices(Array pcPrice)
    {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(pcPrice));
    }

   public double avgPCCalc() 
   {
       int sum = 0;
       for (int i=0; i < pcPrice.length; i++)
       {
           sum = (int) (sum + pcPrice[i]);
       }
       double average = sum / (double)pcPrice.length;
       return average;
   }
}
```

EDIT: And just so you're aware, main(String[] args) is where your program will always start, from there you call other methods and do your work. Nothing else will be calling your main method.

EDIT2: If you'd like to have a conversation about your coding practices shoot me a message, I see you've changed your question and you're missing some basic concepts that would help you easily solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are better in loops, in this case, I would to something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class pcCalculate {

    double[] pcPrice = new double [10];
    public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner price = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0; i< pcPrice.length; i++){
    System.out.print("Set Price " + (i + 1) + ":");
    pcPrice[i] = price.nextDouble();
    }
displayPCPrices();
System.out.println("The average is :" + avgPCCalc());
}

public void displayPCPrices()
{
    System.out.println("The prices are: " + "\n");
    for(int i = 0; i< pcPrice.length; i++){
    System.out.print(pcPrice[i] + " ");
    }

}

   public double avgPCCalc() 
   {
    double sum = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < pcPrice.length; i++)
            {
                 sum += pcPrice[i];
           }
    double average = sum / 10;
    return average;
   }


}
```

Comment: When attempting to run this program main keeps screaming about how it cant run a non static variable of pcPrice , displayPCPrices , and avgPCCalc